# video.js - fadeOut-Time

Tags: video.js

First of all - video.js is a nice tool !

In Firefox/Chrome - controlbar-fadeIn is fast - that's nice. But fadeOut is very very slow.
In IE 7/8/9 there is no fadeIn/ fadeOut.

How I can set the FadeOut-Time?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I have found answer:

.vjs-fade-out {
 -webkit-transition: visibility 0s linear 1.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
 -moz-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
 -ms-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
 -o-transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear;
 transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s,opacity 0.5s linear
}

Comment: IE 7/8/9 do not support CSS3 transitions, so they are not shown the fade (it could probably be done using JavaScript, but the way we're going with browser technology, better chalk this up as _graceful degradation_). IE10 does support some CSS3 transitions, and looking at the CSS, it should work fine there (though I haven't tested it).